# what is the total memory usage of all my processes?

Tags: users, memory-usage

I am on a shared host and I am only allowed to use so much RAM. How can I find out how much I am currently using ? I know top and free and ps and some other tools, but they usually only display memory for the entire system, not user-specific. There is also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131303/linux-how-to-measure-actual-memory-usage-of-an-application-or-process) SF post which gives me the impression measuring memory usage is not a s trivial as it seems.

Maybe some esoteric ps switch plus some shell scripting ? I am reasonably sure I am not the first one with that issue, so there is probably a straight-forward solution, just can't seem to find it...

Comment: Which form of VPS are you using, VM based, like vmware or xen ? or container based like Virtuozzo, OpenVZ or Linux V Servers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should show the total *resident set size* (non-swapped physical memory) in KB.

```
ps uU username | awk '/^username/ { total += $6 } END { print total }'
```

If you need the *virtual memory size*, try:

```
ps uU username | awk '/^username/ { total += $5 } END { print total }'
```

Comment: I'd combine the two....

ps uU username| awk '/^username/ { vtotal += $5 } { rtotal += $6}  END { print "R " rtotal " V " vtotal }'

This is for a linux machine, ps flags and awk anchors will vary with different versions of ps

Comment: The OP mentioned free(1), which afaik is a Linux-ism. And the 'u' option without hyphen puts ps into BSD-style output mode, which is fairly consistent across platforms. (I tested on Linux, OS X, and FreeBSD.) But I do like the idea of producing combined output!